# Check constraint is violated even though the data is corresponding with it

Tags: mysql, datagrip

I just have started learning MySQL. So I use datagrip and create a table with this query:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
    customerid CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (customerid),
    CONSTRAINT cekcustomerid CHECK ( customerid LIKE 'CU[0-9][0-9][0-9]')
);
```

then I added the data with

```
INSERT INTO customer
VALUE ('CU001');

[2021-05-09 21:10:28] [HY000][3819] Check constraint 'cekcustomerid' is violated.
```

The data that I input is corresponding with the check constraint. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using SQL Server syntax not applicable to MySql.

In MySql `[]` are not wildcard characters when used with the operator `LIKE`.

You can use [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
    customerid CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (customerid),
    CONSTRAINT cekcustomerid CHECK (customerid REGEXP '^CU[0-9]{3}$')
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c8e08336d9c6c32a0320a6ccec40bcd).